# How to deal with precision point?

Tags: java, precision

I want to print float values as an integer that is if the value is 70.0 then 70 and but if it is 70.1 then it should not change into int value as 70.1?

Comment: It is unclear what data type do you want to receive if the argument is `70.1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigDecimal` for your values and call method [stripTrailingZeros()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros) to remove zeros.

You can check it:

```
new BigDecimal("15.00").stripTrailingZeros();
```

will return:

```
15
```

And for float value:

```
new BigDecimal("15.1").stripTrailingZeros();
```

Will return:

```
15.1
```